# Why position of racers in this track not in order?

Tags: olympics, athletics

I am referring to Athletics - Round 1 - Heat 3 of Women's 200m Olympics 2021:

[image]

Why position of racers in this track not in order ?

Comment: Because listing runners by finishing order rather than the lane they ran in seems more useful? Honestly not sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: Agreed - this looks like a misunderstanding of the information being presented, and when the misunderstanding is cleared up there's no question left.

Comment: Most likely, but that still seems like a valid question, just reposed - no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lane" refers to which lane they raced in (there are 8 lanes on a track).  The racers start on a staggered start, as the inner lanes are shorter distances otherwise.  In the 200m race the racers will not switch lanes - they'll stay in the same lane the entire time.  See the [rules here](https://www.worldathletics.org/disciplines/sprints/200-metres).

Beyond being informative as to which lane they raced in, that column is not useful - it is not related to the rank they finished in - and so it is not used to sort.

Comment: Although sightly oddly, the lanes for the Olympic sprint finals are numbered 2-9.

Comment: Maybe that's because it's "bad" to be on the outside or inside lane, and so they don't give anyone that number (1)?  (I.e., as superstition, not like the number 1 vs 2 matters...)

Comment: After a quick bit of digging: 9 lanes is good because it gives a "spare" lane which can be used if someone is re-instated from a semi-final or similar due to an infringement by another athlete, but if they have only 8 athletes they'll use lanes 2-9 because it avoids the inner lane with the tightest curve. (Doesn't _quite_ explain why they use 2-9 in the 100m, but at that point it may just be easier to do it that way).